# I can't get click and drag to work with my Wacom Bamboo P&T

Tags: 10.10, kubuntu, wacom, bamboo, graphics-tablet

I get my Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch apparently working (By using [Martin Owens' PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11815/how-to-install-wacom-bamboo-pen/11822#11822)), but whenever I try to click and drag something -- for example to move a window -- it will only register as a click. In other words: The "button up" event is generated right after the "button down" event no matter how long I hold it in.

This is the same whether I use the tip of the pen, the buttons on the pen or the buttons on the pad.

However: Clicking and dragging works perfectly in the login-screen, both before logging in for the first time and after logging out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since click and drag works in the login-screen it must be some per-user thing. I used to have `kde-config-tablet`, which offered me a GUI for configuring the tablet inside of the control center, installed. After removing this package, clicking and dragging started to work.

This solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge kde-config-tablet
```

Comment: Interesting problem, good that you've figured something interesting out. Do you want to report a bug against kde-config-tablet?

Comment: @Martin Owens: That's probably a good idea. [Bug report here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kcm-tablet/+bug/682178)