# Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch not working after installing doctormo's PPA

Tags: 10.04, wacom

Yesterday I installed doctormo's PPA package of the Wacom drivers to get a new Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch working on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS laptop, as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11815/how-to-install-wacom-bamboo-pen) and dozens of other web pages.  Things were working fine, but today things broke.  Some symptoms:

- right-/middle-clicks don't work
- `xsetwacom list devices` shows nothing/is empty
- clicking causes the mouse pointer to stop moving - it moves again if I move the stylus out of the field and back in

Some extra info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux fl 2.6.32-31-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 18:25:51 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 056a:00d1 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsmod | fgrep wacom
wacom                  32165  0
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.  Happy to provide further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it was due to a missing /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-wacom.conf, which was removed in a packaging screw-up in an update from just a few days ago. After adding in the one from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562 everything worked again. Thanks go to [Favux](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTina6iQ9uaMztA%2BSMUdowJit6e3c1w%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=linuxwacom-discuss).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your wacom tablet isn't being discovered by the underlying usb driver. There is no way that your wacom will work if the usb device isn't plugged in and detected by the kernel.

Check any usb hub, check everything over. Your wacom will have to appear in the lsusb in order for the wacom driver to kick in. Also check your dmesg log to see if it's being junked by some weird kernel error. More logs will be needed to confirm what's going wrong.

Comment: Strange, when I ran lsusb just now it does say Wacom. Maybe I screwed up earlier - I updated my post. Anyway the tablet is directly connected to the laptop's USB port, and I can do basic things like move the mouse around and click. When I plug in the tablet, no new lines show up in dmesg.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a powered USB port? Wacom tablets require a powered port. Not all laptop USB ports are powered. On mine it is a separate port from a main group of USB connections. Try other ports.